# Angular ng-required and ng-disabled directives not working

Tags: angular5, angular-directive

i am new to Angular and have no idea what Angular<4 is all about as i am using Angular5. I have simply created Angular app through angular@Cli and in one of the components i am trying to add a form bellow:

```
<form name="myForm"  novalidate >
<input type="text" name="title"   [(ngModel)]="question.title" ng-required="true" /><br>
<input type="text" name="desc"   [(ngModel)]="question.desc" ng-required="true" /> <br>
<input type="button" (click)="PostQuestion()" ng-disabled="!myForm.title.$valid" name="submit" value="Post question" /> </form>
```

but the problem here is the button(Post question) is not getting disabled even after the condition is false meaning the title field of the is empty. What can be the problem here. Is ng-directive is dependent on some external bootstrap/jquery file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1). Use `[disabled]` instead of `ng-disabled`.                                              2) Use `[attr.required]=" isRequired == true ? 'required' : null "` instead of `ng-required`

Comment: Thanks @hrdkisback, these directives are working but can you tell me why? Why ng-disabled and ng-required are not working as everywhere in tutorials they are using these?

Comment: `ng-disabled` and `ng-required` are supported only in `AngularJS`, you can not use in `Angular-Cli`, problem was you are using angularjs's directives in Angular-Cli project.

Comment: Thanks @hrdkisback. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing angular JS (1.x) and angular (4) directives.

In the latest angular this how you use ng-disabled\

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!ngForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

This is just an example. Please try changing your code

Answer (score 0):

You should use the form.$invalid instead.

```
 <form name="myForm"  novalidate >
     <input type="text" name="title"   ng-model="question.title" ng-required="true" /><br>
     <input type="text" name="desc"   ng-model="question.desc" ng-required="true" /> <br>
     <input type="button" ng-click="PostQuestion()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" name="submit" value="Post question" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but still no luck, same behavior.

Comment: I just noticed your ngModel attributes. They should be ng-model, i edited the code to display it correctly.

Comment: [(ngModel)] was working correctly but ng-Model isn't. I tried your code.

Comment: Thanks, if i remove the javascript snippet from jsfiddle example, ng-disabled does not work. Why is it so? Thats what i asked in my original question also, does ng-disabled/ng-required depend on some other stuff?

Comment: @DevUsman, the solution that darkhouse has provided is for angular1, for angular2 you can use formControls or simply ngControl to access the behavior of the directives

Comment: Thanks @SunilLama but there is no ngControl in RC2. Its strange that why no one is getting here with true skills :/